# how to seperate 1 data into 2 field

Tags: php, arrays, substr

```
[mapping] => Array
        (
            [0] => PO1/KPP1
            [1] => PO2/KPP2
            [2] => PO3/KPP3
            [3] => PO4/KPP4
            [4] => PO5/KPP5
            [5] => PO6/KPP6
            [6] => PO7/KPP7
       )

<?php

$str = "PO1/KPP1"; 
$strarr = split ("/", $str); 

print "$strarr[0] <br />";
print "$strarr[1] <br />" ;
?>
```

i have a data that's i declare like this **PO1/KPP1**.
i want to save PO1 into 1 field and KPP1 into other field.
both are in the sama table.

i know the logic..but i don't know how to interpret into programming.

can i nobody help me.

Comment: _"i know the logic..but i don't know how to interpret into programming."_ - So do research, study, make attempts. SO isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

use http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.phpn to explode data.

```
foreach ($mapping as $value) {
    $pieces = explode("/", $value);
    $dataA = pieces[0];
    $dataB = pieces[1];
//save data...
}
```